# Do resistance levels for financial securities prices exist?

Tags: statistics, econometrics, technical-analysis

I know there is a large controversy about whether or not technical trading rules are profitable and research results depend on asset classes, time frames, trading costs, risk-adjusted return calculation, etc.

Compared to this complexity it seems rather simple to statistically test, if resistance levels exist. One would just have to identify them (which is the hard part, I guess) and then run a statistical test for whether price moves crossing the resistance levels indeed occur less frequently.

Do you know of any study who does this?

Comment: It makes logical sense that they might exist, given the existence of limit orders of the form "once some price hits <nice round number>, trade at market", of too few choices of strikes for exchange-listed options, etc. Some studies do purport to show that they exist, e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348619587_Evidence_and_Behaviour_of_Support_and_Resistance_Levels_in_Financial_Time_Series  or https://doi.org/10.3390/math10203888 . Whether the EMH would stop one from profiting from their possible existence is a different question.